# Reset children value with script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, reset

I try to reset children of `testId`, but it doesn't work.

```
<div id="testId">
 <input type="text" />
 <div>
 <input type="text" />
 </div>
 <select>
 <option>1</option><option>2</option>
 </select>
 </div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">reset</button>
```

All I tested:

```
$("#testId input").each(function() {      this.value = "";  })

$(document).ready(function() {  $('#testId').find('input:text').val('');});

document.getElementById('testId').reset()

 $('#testId')[0].reset();

$('#testId :input').val('');

$('#testId').trigger("reset");

$("#testId").get().reset();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reset()` is a method of  `form` element, just change `div` to `form`

```html
<form id="testId">
 <input type="text" />
 <div>
 <input type="text" />
 </div>
 <select>
 <option>1</option><option>2</option>
 </select>
 </form>
<button onclick="testId.reset()">reset</button>
```

or reset elements manually

```js
function resetDiv() {
  $('#testId input').val('');
  $('#testId select').val(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testId">
 <input type="text" />
 <div>
 <input type="text" />
 </div>
 <select>
 <option>1</option><option>2</option>
 </select>
 </div>
<button onclick="resetDiv()">reset</button>
```